# Determining Reaction Orders

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

Can you figure out the reactant's reaction order (First-order, second-order, third-order, etc.) JUST by looking at a chemical reaction? What if you were given a multi-step reaction? A single step reaction?

For example, can you tell what order $\ce{2NO_2Cl}$ is just by looking at this equation: $$\ce{2NO_2Cl -> 2NO_2 + Cl_2}$$

Or this multistep equation?

$$\ce{NO_2Cl -> NO_2 + Cl}$$

$$\ce{Cl + NO_2Cl -> NO_2 + Cl_2}$$

Comment: This is a common kinetics question... lots of websites discuss it. [Here's chemguide's page on it](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/basicrates/ordermech.html#top). No, you cannot tell the order from the balanced overall reaction. You can tell the order if you are given the mechanism, though.

Comment: By given the mechanism, what do you mean? And how can I derive the order from it?

Comment: Do you mean the graph of reaction path and energy?